# How can I generate the default views in grails?

Tags: grails, groovy, view

Why is the default option of generete views disabled? How can I enable it to create my default views?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TA0KP.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default all views are generated at runtime using [your controller configuration](https://docs.grails.org/latest/guide/scaffolding.html):

```
class BookController {
    static scaffold = Book  // Or any other domain class name
}
```

If you want to generate views (files on disk) a command from the grails CLI in required:

```
grails generate-views Book
```

See the [scaffolding documentation](https://docs.grails.org/latest/guide/scaffolding.html) for more details.